# Chamar funções em C a partir do R

Tags: c, r

Estou precisando otimizar algumas funções que estão na linguagem C, porém utilizando os pacotes de algoritmos genéticos no R.

Existe alguma forma de chamar funções de C no R?

Em matlab eu sei que existe essa possibilidade através de `mex`. No R tem algo parecido?

Comment: O meu Google devolve [Using R — Calling C Code ‘Hello World!’](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1067) que parece explicar bem como ligar as duas linguagens (notaL eu nao sei R, nem experimentei nada desse artigo).

Comment: Olá Bruno. Eu editei a sua pergunta pra alterar o título de forma a deixá-lo mais condizente com a pergunta. Acho que assim ele deve atrair a atenção correta. Se você não gostar da edição, pode alterá-la você mesmo ou até mesmo desfazê-la.

Comment: Obrigado @Luiz Vieira , você saberia me ajudar?

Comment: Por nada. Eu conheço pouco do R, então acho que não consigo ajudar. Mas olhei brevemente o artigo que o @pmg postou pra você e lá parece ter muita informação útil. Pode ir te ajudando até alguém que entende mais postar uma resposta aqui. Se você mesmo descobrir como faz com base nesse artigo, por favor poste você mesmo uma resposta aqui (pois a ideia é manter conhecimento que ajude não apenas a você, mas a outros usuários futuros que podem ter a mesma dúvida). :)

Comment: Bruno, a não ser que você tenha dúvidas mais específicas sobre a interface entre as linguagens, a resposta para a sua pergunta atualmente é "Sim: `.C`, `.Call` e `External`", que podem ser vistas no link postado pelo pmg e também no [livro do Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html), ambos em inglês.

Comment: se você quer exemplo de código, veja o pacote data.table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acho que atualmente a forma mais limpa e mais fácil de integrar códigos de C++ (ou C no seu caso) é usando o [pacote Rcpp (link do CRAN)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) [(site do pacote aqui)](http://www.rcpp.org).

Com o Rcpp você pode definir uma função na própria seção usando a função `cppFunction`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('int soma(int x, int y){ 
            int soma = x+y; 
            return soma;
            }')
soma(1,2)
[1] 3
```

Ou você também pode definir suas funções em um arquivo `.cpp` e usar a função `sourceCpp`. Você vai especificar no cabeçalho do arquivo que você está usando o Rcpp `#include <Rcpp.h>`, `using namespace Rcpp;` e em seguida definir suas funções. Se você estiver usando o RStudio, ao pedir para criar um novo arquivo c++ ele já te dá a estrutura mínima do arquivo.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// This is a simple example of exporting a C++ function to R. You can
// source this function into an R session using the Rcpp::sourceCpp 
// function (or via the Source button on the editor toolbar). Learn
// more about Rcpp at:
//
//   http://www.rcpp.org/
//   http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html
//   http://gallery.rcpp.org/
//

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {
  return x * 2;
}


// You can include R code blocks in C++ files processed with sourceCpp
// (useful for testing and development). The R code will be automatically 
// run after the compilation.
//

/*** R
timesTwo(42)
*/
```

Bom, com isso já dá para você começar a tentar  passar o código para o R. Para mais detalhes eu recomendo o [livro do Hadley](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) para uma introdução mais geral e [os vignettes do pacote](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) e o [livro do Dirk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461468671) para mais detalhes sobre o Rcpp.

Comment: Perfeito @Carlos Cinelli , muito bom seu post! Me ajudou bastante.